# How can I build 64-bit hvx libary?

Tags: android, tensorflow, 64-bit, hexagon-dsp

I am trying to run TensorFlow on SD820's Hexagon DSP. I have followed the instructions and successfully built HVX in 32-bit and using libhexagon_nn_skel.so and libhexagon_controller.so, I have run TensorFlow sample app on Hexagon successfully. 
By the way, the app I am developing is a system app and need to be run under 64-bit environment.
I have searched for solution how to build 64-bit HVX but no luck. Can anyone help me to build HVX libraries in 64-bit?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which SDK release are you using?

Comment: @BrianCain I am using Hexagon SDK 3.0 along with hvx commit 721b2d58f as described [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/hvx).